# C List: dealing with typedef

Tags: c, list

if there a way to write this code with a typedef for the struct?

```
struct s_parola{
    char info[40];
    struct s_parola *next;
};
```

I tried with this code but it isn't correct:

```
typedef struct {
    char info[40];
    t_parola *next;
} t_parola;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is that you're receiving an "unknown type s_parola" within your struct, it's because you're trying to use the typedef before it's defined. You could do the following instead:

```
typedef struct s_parola s_parola;

struct s_parola {
    char info[40];
    s_parola *next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works best for me:

```
struct _s_parola {
  char info[40];
  struct _s_parola *next;
};

typedef struct _s_parola s_parola;

int main() {
  s_parola p;
}
```

<del>For using `s_parola` as a type inside `s_parola` you need to use `struct`</del>. However this way you can use `s_parola` without `struct` anywhere else in your program.

**Edit**
@JamesReed 's answer works too, I'm just not comfortable using

```
typedef struct s_parola s_parola;
```

Might be 100% OK, but I am not comfortable. I am actually curious if that is standard compliant. If it is, it's a better solution than mine. **If someone could answer would be great.**

Comment: Placing the typedef before the struct definition allows me to use the typedef within the struct definition. Don't know if that's implementation-specific, though.

Comment: I believe §6.2.3 of the standard deals with this:

If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a
translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities.
Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
— label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
— the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any32)
  of the keywords struct, union, or enum);

Comment: That's not to say that this won't break if you try to compile it in a C++ compiler, though